# newcommand with arguments within another newcommand with arguments

Tags: macros

If I define a newcommand within another newcommand, and both the inner and outer have arguments, how do I access the arguments of the inner newcommand? In the example below, where I have '***' I want to access the '#1' argument that is passed into the inner newcommand.

```
\newcommand{\defTerm}[3]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1][]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#***}{}}%
            {\textbf{\tooltip{#2}{\begin{varwidth}{10cm}#3\end{varwidth}}}}%
            {\textbf{\tooltip{#***}{\begin{varwidth}{10cm}#3\end{varwidth}}}}%
    }%
}
```

An example usage of this is:

```
\defTerm{ETNZ}{Emirates Team New Zealand}{The winner of the 35th America's Cup}
```

then in the text:

```
\ETNZ was the winner in Bermuda. \ETNZ[They] beat BMW Oracle Racing.
```

### UPDATE

Corrected `\ETNZ{They}` to `\ETNZ[They]` in my example.

Comment: Welcome. Did you try to use `##1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#` is doubled in each level of nested definitions:

```
\newcommand{\defTerm}[3]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1][]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{}}%
            {\textbf{\tooltip{#2}{\begin{varwidth}{10cm}#3\end{varwidth}}}}%
            {\textbf{\tooltip{##1}{\begin{varwidth}{10cm}#3\end{varwidth}}}}%
    }%
}
```

Another example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\foo}[3]{%
  foo=(#1, #2, #3)\par
  \def\foobar##1##2{%
    foo=(#1, #2, #3) foobar=(##1, ##2)\par
    \newcommand{\foobarbaz}[1]{%
      foo=(#1, #2, #3) foobar=(##1, ##2) foobarbaz=####1\par
    }%
    \foobarbaz{##2}%
  }%
  \foobar{#2}{#3}%
}

\foo{A}{B}{C}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks - solved... after I corrected my own example above.